# WordPress REST API always misses parameters - rest_missing_callback_param

Tags: api, rest-api

I tried to test out WordPress REST API by deleting a user (using basic authentication just to see if everything works), but no matter how I try to pass the parameters to the destination server, I always get rest_missing_callback_param.

Here is a screenshot from POSTMAN:

[image: Authentication is correct. Parameters set.]

It happens even when I tried with PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://web.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/3" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 

    array( 'Authorization: Bearer ' .$authToken )

);

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $http_query );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$output = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
```

What could possibly be a problem here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to deliver another argument - the `reassign`.

"Reassign the deleted user's posts and links to this user ID."  - [WP API documentation](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/users/)

Please try like this:

```
DELETE http://web.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/3?reassign=NEW_USER_ID
```

Comment: You might also need to pass `force=true`, so the url would look like this:
`http://web.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/<id>?reassign=<id>&force=true`